# Difference between calling sql() and using Spark API call()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, scala-collections

I am new to Spark/Scala/Hive. Am just wondering if there are any differences between calling

```
spark = new SparkSession(...).getHiveContext()
spark.sql("SELECR * FROM table")
```

and

```
spark = new SparkSession(...).getHiveContext() // not using
spark.read.table(table).select(from("*"))
```

??

Particularly, are there any performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

These two snippets have the same run-time performance.

The second API is safer, is you make a typo or try to used some non supported operation it will give you a quick and clear compilation error. It's funny that you wrote `SELECR` and not `SELECT`, that a good illustration of this point :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do they still share the same run-time performance if it's for other kind of queries? Say sorting, grouping? Also, I saw this article by hortonworks: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html, but was wondering if I enable hivecontext, does it make any difference, since it will be using HiveQL?